# How to pass data from ContainerRequestFilter to resource in Jersey framework

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I was trying to use ContainerRequestFilter for my rest webservice application to authenticate input request. Once the request authenticated i need to pass a object to resouce with all the information. can some one please let me know how can we achieve this?

Thanks for your help..

~MS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your filter you need to pull in the servlet request:

```
@Context
private transient HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
```

And store your data as an attribute:

```
this.servletRequest.setAttribute("My data", myObject);
```

And then in a resource you can pull in the servletRequest and use:

```
Object myObject = this.servletRequest.getAttribute("My data");
```

Comment: As a curiosity.. Why did you mark HttpServletRequest as transient?